# Cucumber - Capybara - Selenium for phones and tablets

Tags: android, iphone, selenium, cucumber, capybara

We currently have a lot of cucumber tests that we use to test our mobile web-app on desktop browsers. However, i recently heard a rumor that it is possible to use some sort of remote web-driver to run our tests on actual devices instead of just on the desktop browser. However when I look up the android or iPhone web-drivers, they seem to be deprecated and recommend me using selendroid or appium, which neither seem to support browser-testing.

Today, we are only able to use our cucumber-tests for acceptance testing and as a first line of defense when doing regression tests. We still have to spend countless hours doing manual testing on around 10-20 different devices with different OS versions and browsers. Being able to run our cucumber-tests on the actual devices themselves could save us tons of time, as we'd be able to run these tests in parallel with the manual tests, and only focus our manual tests on detecting visual issues instead of also having to test the functionality of each page in our web-app.

Is it possible to run our cucumber tests on phones and tablets, and in that case how?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but in case this helps folks, here's some basic information:

Take a look at [Appium](http://appium.io/), which provides automation (with cucumber) for Android and iOS applications or mobile-web and for real devices or emulation/simulation.

There's a decent setup tutorial [here](http://shashikantjagtap.net/ios-automated-testing-in-the-bdd-with-appium-cucumber-on-mac-osx/), for a web-app. Setup for a mobile-website is similar but not as easy to find. Take a look here if you want [Appium on SauceLabs](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2013/10/setting-up-ios-automation-on-saucelabs-with-cucumber-and-appium/).

Most sites you visit will say "it's easy!". I found that not to be the case; you'll see many requests for help and the specific devices and versions that you're working with all make a big difference. This is especially true if you are working with older devices, in which case you'll need to look at [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/setup.html) for Android.

Assuming you're working with more than just a small group, you'll need to become familiar with configuring Cucumber to work with different devices and configurations: [profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml) may become your new best friend. There's also some profile help in [this post](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Cucumber-Backgrounder).